# Create trigger on system journal

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald

There is a script ([found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4331330/1915723)), intended to monitor a log file: if keyword triggers then execute a command:

```
journalctl -f | \
while read line ; do
    echo "$line" | grep "apcu"
    if [ $? = 0 ]
    then
           systemctl restart php7.2-fpm.service
    fi
done
```

I created and enabled a systemd service with this lines:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/home/alex/journal-trigger.sh
StandardOutput=file:/home/alex/journal-trigger.log
StandardError=file:/home/alex/journal-trigger.error.log
```

This is a temporary measure, which restarts php service when apcu.so module fails. However, I faced one downside (when a command comprises 'apcu'):

```
sudo php cachetool.phar apcu:cache:info --fcgi

In FastCGI.php line 133:          
  FastCGI error: Stream got blocked, or terminated. (/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock)

In Socket.php line 525:
  Stream got blocked, or terminated.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: If your grep is not specific enough, then change your grep to match the message you *actually* want to match? This looks really fragile though, I'd be inclined to do it based on application metrics (or the lack thereof) instead if possible.

Comment: I see, thanks, grep + regular expression. More robust solution I hope I will find soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed this issue by `grep kernel\:\ traps\:.*apcu\.so`
But the real fix was at the application level: `apcu_clear_cache()` was unintentionally left in my PHP code on prod server...